# Get paged outside of loop?

Tags: loop, paged

Is it possible to get paged outside of the standard WP loop?

I already use this inside the loop:

```
<?php if ( $paged >= 2 ) { ?>  Some text for the 2nd page on up  <?php } ?>
```

But I'd like to be able to echo some text outside the loop on all pages two and greater. Possible? Or a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
if ( is_paged() )
  echo 'some text';
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Paged_Page

Comment: This works fine inside the loop; I need something that works outside of the loop.

Comment: It should work outside The Loop as well, unless you're [using query_posts() wrong](http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html).

Comment: I'm using the standard WP loop.

Comment: So, you're saying that it works inside `while ( have_posts() ) ...` but not before it? Try deactivating all plugins; then try switching to the default theme.

Comment: Argg....  Had another php conditonal for paged higher up in the code that was conflicting. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can make a "second" Loop like this:

```
<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  if ($paged >= 2) {echo "your content";}
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now you can use the `$paged` where ever you want.

Like in the comments quoted this was not the best solution. It was really quick and dirty.

After a little test:
You can use `$paged` outside the loop.
But you can query the active page where you want in the code with

```
<?php get_query_var('paged'); ?>
```

Because the active page is a parameter of the active URL. For your question:

```
if (get_query_var('paged') >=2) {
  echo "text for pages from 2 and up";
} else {
  echo "text for the first page";
}
```

Comment: That's wasteful.

Comment: You are right it is a quick and dirty solution. But it is a solution at all. I think a good way is to output the text in the loop, like in a DIV-Element and place it with CSS.

Comment: Can't get this to work with the standard WP loop....